# How to create Linked textbox in worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a textbox or a caption in an excel worksheet, that displays the value of some cell from this worksheet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use a textbox control as Lance suggests, but there are other, perhaps better ways:

If you create an autoshape textbox (Insert->Picture->AutoShapes) you can link it to a *single* cell by selecting it, then type (for example) "=A1" into the formula bar. You can then format and position it as you like.

That's pretty cool, but not as cool as this: if you copy a *range* of cells, and then hold down the shift key as you choose the Edit menu, you'll see an option "Paste picture link". If you do this, it pastes a picture of the cells which gets updated when the cell values change. As Michael Caine never said, "not a lot of people know that".

Note: I'm talking here about Excel 2003. I assume it still works in 2007, though the location of the various commands, etc. will have changed.

Comment: That is amazing. I've been working on Excel for 10 years and I never heard of this before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you don't need vba, you can just put the control on the sheet, and link it to the cell (when in control design mode, just right-click on it and go to properties).

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2013:

1. Copy the desired range
2. Do NOT create a text box
3. Go to an area near where you want the "picture" of the referenced cells
4. With "Ctrl" key pressed right click - paste special - other paste options - linked picture

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that it does work in Excel 2007 (you don't need to hold down shift).

Home tab->Paste (select down arrow)->As Picture->Paste Picture link